# Get django source code directory path running on a VM using scripts

Tags: django, python-3.x

I need to get the source code directory of a Django app running on a VM

I just have the VM's details and I know that there is a Django app running.

I can get the port by running the following command using SSH

```
sudo netstat -plant | grep "LISTEN.*python3" | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d ":" -f2
```

After that, I need to know the directory of the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got one solution if there is only one Django app running on your VM:

```
#We can also use ps command to get PID, I am using this to get PID and Port
PROCESS_ID=`sudo netstat -plant | grep "LISTEN.*python3" | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d "/" -f1`

APP_DIR=`sudo lsof | grep python3.*${PROCESS_ID}.*DIR | awk 'NR==1{print $9}'

PORT=`sudo netstat -plant | grep "LISTEN.*python3" | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d ":" -f2`
```

The APP_DIR will have the absolute path of Django app running.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get a path of the Django app from a 'netstat' or 'ps' command, you find the path is through manual lookup.
Start looking into '/var/www/ folder'.
If you want to know without much searching, check the server configuration, see the Nginx or apache2 file in '/etc/nginx/sites-available' folder you will find the path there.

Comment: I don't need to get this from within the code. I have updated the question.

Comment: Did the figure it out? If so please mark this as answer. @Ashwani